# How to properly check for a clicked element using Jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, click, css-transitions

I'm trying to figure out the correct way or better yet a clean and precise way of sliding out a nav block upon an element being clicked and then hiding the nav block if that same element is clicked. This is what I have so far:

```
$('.menu').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $('#pic-slideNav').css('display', 'block');

    if ($.browser.webkit) {
        $('#pic-wrapper').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(250px,0px)');
        console.log('This is Chrome');
    } else {
        $('#pic-wrapper').css('transform', 'translate(250px,0px)');
        console.log('This is Everything else');

    }
});
```

I am also checking for browser type so I can pass the correct css rule.

**Updated code that is working for me:**

```
$('.menu-icon').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if($('#pic-slideNav').is(':visible')) {
        $('#pic-slideNav').hide();
        if ($.browser.webkit) {
            $('#pic-wrapper').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(0px,0px)');
            console.log('This is Chrome');
        } else {
            $('#pic-wrapper').css('transform', 'translate(0px,0px)');
            console.log('This is Everything else');
        }

    } else {
        $('#pic-slideNav').show();
        if ($.browser.webkit) {
            $('#pic-wrapper').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(250px,0px)');
            console.log('This is Chrome');
        } else {
            $('#pic-wrapper').css('transform', 'translate(250px,0px)');
            console.log('This is Everything else');
        }
    }

});
```

I'm sure there is a cleaner way of achieving this but it works.

Comment: check out jquery's `toggle()` function...is that what you're looking for? http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: @iight toggle() doesn't support animation.

Comment: $.browser is deprecated in latest versions of jquery.

Comment: I don't think you should mix css and jquery. Better to add/remove CSS classes, and then control their values in a css file.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini thanks! so i guess you could simply toggle the classes, right?

Comment: @jamietre I am using the latest version of Jquery and $.browser still works for me. But I guess I can use Modernizr for that type of detection. Thanks

Comment: You might want to learn more about jQuery animation, chaining animation events and stuff like that. You can do a lot with it.

Comment: It's deprecated - not actually removed - which just means it's risky. In this case i think it's very risky because it does not appear in development builds anymore so i suspect it's slated for destruction soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/3rx5y/1/)

```
var i=0;
jQuery("#btn").click(function() {
    var t = (Math.pow(-1,i))*160;
    jQuery("#id").stop(true, false).animate({
        left: t
    }, 500);
    i = (i>10) ? 0 : (i+1);
});​
```

Comment: I guess what I am truly looking to accomplish is what Mashable has done for their new responsive site. When < 320px wide you get an icon that when clicked displays the hidden menu and transforms the main body. What I have works all I need to do is have it revert back when that element is again clicked.